# ActionScript StrictMode (beginner)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flash-builder

How do I turn on the strict mode in Flash Builder 4?

**--update**

I found something about "Preferences -> Actionscript 3 Settings", but there is no such option in Flash Builder preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project->Properties->Flex Compiler->Enable strict type checking.

But it should be enabled by default.

Comment: Are you using it in the project somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Check that Build Automatically is selected, that could be causing your confusion. Or if you like it deselected, try a clean/build. You'll also have to be using it within your 'default' application somewhere (referring to it in the source) for it to find errors.

Comment: yeah, I realized later that it need to be linked with some source.. (my reaction: "WTF!?")